# How Google identifies an Android project/developer

Tags: android

I just would like to know how Google identifies a project (other than package name, or code) or a developer of an Android app. From what I think there is some data from your Android Studio that gets inserted in the apk. Do you know how to edit that data?

If you are building with an older api, I see that there is a file build-data.properties in the apk.
In this file there is some data like build.time, build.build_id or build.timestamp. Do you know how to change this data from Android Studio?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google identifies a project by three properties:

1. `packageName` from AndroidManifest.xml
2. used certificate+RSA key for signing the APK file or appBunlde (Which keystore and signing key to use is usually denoted in the gradle configuration of a Android Studio project). To change the signature you have to generate a new keystore and configure gradle to use it for signing your APK.
3. For apps that are published in Google Play Store Google account used for uploading and publishing the app.

If you side-load APK files directly to a device (either via `adb` or by downloading the APK file(s) from somewhere, the device uses the first two properties to identify an app/develop.

#### APK signature

Regarding the [APK signature](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning) there are currently 4 different versions how to sign an APK file. An APK can be signed by one or multiple of those signature standards, you can even sign an APK by all four versions at the same time.

APK signature v1 is the old Java `jarsigner` (contained in the APK in several files in the directory `/META-INF`.

[APK signature v2](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2) & [v3](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v3) do sign the APK file directly and add the signature invisible into the APK file in a section not covered by the ZIP specification.

[APK signature v4](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v4) is a detached signature so the signature is saved in a separate file outside of the APK file e.g. named `<apk name>.apk.idsig`.

Comment: Thank you but I really think these are not the only ways. Some info is even stored in a text file in the apk - build-data.properties

Comment: here is how the file looks like - https://github.com/Scarabei/AndroidArtifacts/blob/master/com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement.11.0.4/src/build-data.properties

Comment: I see that the file can be excluded from the apk- packagingOptions{ 'build-data.properties'} but I am not sure if there is any more data in the apk that can identify you

Comment: @AndreiCiuca The file `build-data.properties` you have linked to does not contain and information about a user it is simply the dump of the settings used for building this library. Every app that uses this version will contain the identical file. Therefore it can't be used to identify an Android project or app developer.